# How to extract very nested json without pattern

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pyspark, etl

I've been trying to normalize a JSON file and wanted a python(pandas) or pyspark script the more generic as possible that can extract data from a very nested mongodb JSON - it comes from a third party API and saved in MongoDB - and return it in a relational dataset so we can consume it from the datalake.
There are a lot of records and fields, so we can't do it in only one dataframe. Also, the layout does not have a pattern.

Could you please help us?
What is the best way to do this in best practices and, if possible, recursively?

Below is a chunk of the json file

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migueelcruz/sample_json/main/sample.json

We expect multiple dataframes that link each other so we can consume data like a relational database. Also, the files must be like a database table.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Uncertain levels of nesting, highly nested schema, potentially using dynamic values as field names, single bloated document... These are all the anti-patterns observed in your schema. I don't think it is practical to process the document at current state. You may want to consult the data source owner to provide a more sensible format of data for you to process.

Comment: Deserialize it using json module

Comment: i would add on to @ray comment that very nested might be most applicable to a python dict as opposed to a pandas dataframe which is more akin to a structured table.

Comment: @ray, actually the data comes from the brazilian government API so it's not possible to ask them to change the format.

Comment: @MiguelBotelho sorry to hear that. You might want to look up if they have some documents to indicate the data model spec and see if the data have a pattern for you process it

Answer (score 0):

A way to approach this problem would be using the `json` module to deserialize the data into a python dictionary.

```py
# Get the data
import urllib.request as urllib
link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migueelcruz/sample_json/main/sample.json"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()

# Deserialize
import json
data = json.loads(myfile)
data
```

Now the way you would get the data is using python dictionaries syntax.

i.e if you want to get `eventos` which is under `dados` which is under `eventos` would be:

```py
data["dados"]["nfe"]["eventos"]
```